# Google Script: Select file from folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script in Google Spreadsheet that imports data from a .csv file. Currently the file name to import is hard coded. I want to pre-empt my import with a selection from a list of the contents of a folder. In this way I can date-stamp the csv files and choose which I want to import.

So the file to import will be the file I select from the list displayed.

Can anyone help with the code for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can find lots of code examples to do that, one of my favorites (ha ha) is [this one](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/doc-list-viewer)

You will have to remove some parts that you don't need but everything is explained and fairly simple.

That said, your question is not suitable for this forum, see the article about [questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)